# pure css horizontal accordion: how to have panel open on load

Tags: html, css, accordion, onload

I created a horizontal accordion using the target: method mentioned here:

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/create-css-based-content/

While the accordion works great, I wanted to have the first panel of the accordion be open when the page loads.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be better to use only Javascript.

1. Add an ID to the anchor inside the section that needs to be open:

   ```
   <section id="about">
       <h2><a id="tab-active" href="#about">About Us</a></h2>
       <p>Tab content here</p>
   ```
2. Add Javascript to click the anchor automatically:

   ```
   document.getElementById('tab-active').click();
   ```

**Here's the full example provided by you, now with Javascript:**

```js
//JS
document.getElementById('tab-active').click();
```

```css
/*CSS*/
/*Define Accordion box*/
.accordion { 
     width:830px;
     overflow:hidden; 
     margin:10px auto; 
     color:#474747; 
     background:#414141; 
     padding:10px; 
}

.accordion section{ 
      float:left;
      overflow:hidden; 
      color:#333; 
      cursor:pointer; 
      background: #333; 
      margin:3px; 
}
.accordion section:hover {
      background:#444;
}

.accordion section p { 
      display:none; 
}

.accordion section:after{
      position:relative;
      font-size:24px;
      color:#000;
      font-weight:bold;
}
.accordion section:nth-child(1):after{ content:'1'; }
.accordion section:nth-child(2):after{ content:'2'; }
.accordion section:nth-child(3):after{ content:'3'; }
.accordion section:nth-child(4):after{ content:'4'; }
.accordion section:nth-child(5):after{ content:'5'; }.accordion section:target { 
      background:#FFF; 
      padding:10px;
}
.accordion section:target:hover { 
      background:#FFF; 
}
.accordion section:target h2 {
      width:100%;
}
.accordion section:target h2 a{ 
      color:#333; 
      padding:0;
}
.accordion section:target p {
      display:block;
}
.accordion section h2 a{
      padding:8px 10px;
      display:block; 
      font-size:16px; 
      font-weight:normal;
      color:#eee; 
      text-decoration:none; 
}

.horizontal section{ 
      width:5%; 
      height:250px; 
      -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease-out; 
      -webkit-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
      -o-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
      transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
}

/*Position the number of the slide*/
.horizontal section:after{
      top:140px;
      left:15px;
}

/*Header of closed slide*/
.horizontal section h2 { 
     -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
     -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
     transform: rotate(90deg);
     width:240px; 
     position:relative; 
     left:-100px; 
     top:85px;
} 
/*On mouse over open slide*/
.horizontal :target{ 
     width:73%;
     height:230px; 
}
.horizontal :target h2{ 
     top:0px;
     left:0;
     -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
     -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
     transform: rotate(0deg); 
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="accordion horizontal">
    <section id="about">
    <h2><a id="tab-active" href="#about">About Us</a></h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elemaentum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.</p>
    </section>
 
    <section id="services">
    <h2><a href="#services">Services</a></h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.</p>
    </section>
 
    <section>
        <h2>Blog</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.</p>
    </section>
 
    <section>
        <h2>Portfolio</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.</p>
    </section>
 
    <section>
        <h2>Contact</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lobortis massa. Nunc viverra velit leo, sit amet elementum mi. Fusce posuere nunc a mi tempus malesuada. Curabitur facilisis rhoncus eros eget placerat. Aliquam semper mauris sit amet justo tempor nec lacinia magna molestie. Etiam placerat congue dolor vitae adipiscing. Aliquam ac erat lorem, ut iaculis justo. Etiam mattis dignissim gravida. Aliquam nec justo ante, non semper mi. Nulla consectetur interdum massa, vel porta enim vulputate sed. Maecenas elit quam, egestas eget placerat non, fringilla vel eros. Nam vehicula elementum nulla sed consequat. Phasellus eu erat enim. Praesent at magna non massa dapibus scelerisque in eu lorem.</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: i'm not familiar with javascript, what goes in the #anchorID?

Comment: I tried this JS code but it still doesn't work...any advice?

Comment: I have edited this with the solution, please see if that works.

Comment: Matheus, this is awesome!  I have a follow up question.  This opens the accordion, but it acts as a click so it jumps the page to where the accordion is.  Is there a way to turn off the jumping?  Ideally, I want the first panel to be open by default, but without the page jumping that comes with it.

Comment: Dave, are you able to upload your code into Fiddle? On my point of view the Accordion is supposed to open a tab with the information containing it, nothing else. Run the Code Snippet above to see this clearly and let me know.

Comment: the snippet works great.  I changed it to this and it started to work: 
<script>
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('tab-active').click();}  My issue is that my accordion is in the middle of the page, so when it loads the first panel opens, but it jumps to the middle of the page where the accordion is as if someone clicked on it.

Comment: Glad to hear you made it Dave! I didn't realize that you would use it with other components!